# Lumen/Laravel - Method to extract specific property from objects in an array of objects?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, lumen

I have the following data:

```
    [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "test1",
      "created_at": "2020-01-30 15:55:44",
      "updated_at": "2020-01-30 15:55:44"
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "test12",
      "created_at": "2020-01-30 15:55:44",
      "updated_at": "2020-01-30 15:55:44"
    }, {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "test123",
      "created_at": "2020-01-30 15:55:44",
      "updated_at": "2020-01-30 15:55:44"
    }, {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "test1234",
      "created_at": "2020-01-30 15:55:44",
      "updated_at": "2020-01-30 15:55:44"
    }, {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "test12345",
      "created_at": "2020-01-30 15:55:44",
      "updated_at": "2020-01-30 15:55:44"
    }, {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "test123456",
      "created_at": "2020-01-30 15:55:44",
      "updated_at": "2020-01-30 15:55:44"
    }, {
      "id": 7,
      "name": "test1234567",
      "created_at": "2020-01-30 15:55:44",
      "updated_at": "2020-01-30 15:55:44"
    }, {
      "id": 8,
      "name": "test12345678",
      "created_at": "2020-01-30 15:55:44",
      "updated_at": "2020-01-30 15:55:44"
    }, {
      "id": 9,
      "name": "test123456789",
      "created_at": "2020-01-30 15:55:44",
      "updated_at": "2020-01-30 15:55:44"
    }, {
      "id": 10,
      "name": "test1234567890",
      "created_at": "2020-01-30 15:55:44",
      "updated_at": "2020-01-30 15:55:44"
    }, {
      "id": 11,
      "name": "test12345678901",
      "created_at": "2020-01-30 15:55:44",
      "updated_at": "2020-01-30 15:55:44"
    }, {
      "id": 12,
      "name": "test123456789012",
      "created_at": "2020-01-30 15:55:44",
      "updated_at": "2020-01-30 15:55:44"
    }]
```

This data was retrieved via eloquent model, like this:

```php
$ad_groups = Ad_user::find($request->decodedToken->user_id)->ad_groups()->get();
```

I don't know if any "inherited" functionality of eloquent model still resides within `$ad_groups`, thats why Im posting it here for you so you know what we have to work with ^^

What I basically want to accomplish is to get the ids extraced. I could of course just write a foreach loop. But I'm new to Lumen/Laravel and I'd like to know whether there is also some awesome method like `...>getMeWhatIWant()` available in this context or not :D

Comment: [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) can easily do that.

Comment: @04FS For some reason, this isn't recognized as an array, but an object. I ran is_array and is_object over it and checked with if/else.
When I use array_column, I get this error:
array_column() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given 
Why is that, what can I do about it?

Comment: That's because eloquent returns an object which is a Collection of models, therefore you can't use that as array. However this allows you to use some useful methods on your data (you can see all the available ones in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#available-methods)) which are already implemented in Laravel core

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `pluck` method on a Laravel collection ([official docs here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-pluck)).

You just have to pass the column name that you want to retrieve as first parameter:

```php
$ids = $ad_groups->pluck('id');
dd($ids);
```